# Do I still need woff or eot if I'm using fonts.com?

Tags: html, fonts

I'm not sure if I mis-understood how services like fonts.com or google fonts work.  Basically I created a website.  In the html, I embedded javascript snippet like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/somelongapiekey"></script>
```

Once I did that, I could reference new font families in my css like so `font-family:'Some new font from font.com';`.

Just recently, the client's backend developer asked me to give him the woff and eot files for the fonts I'm using.  I told him that i dont have them because i'm using fonts.com.  Then he responded by asking, "Then how are you able to get the fonts to work in all the other browsers?  Don't you need the woff and eot files to make it work on all the major browsers?"

Did I mis-understand something?  I assumed fonts.com takes care of cross browser compliance and any other issues i haven't considered.  Does the client's developer need the eot/woff files for other reasons I haven't considered?

Comment: The great thing about these services is that they work in all (mayor) browsers. You only need to include them into the website. Personally i prefer to add them to the css (google fonts) thru an `@import` command to keep it in one document.

Comment: He might need the files, but he's not told you why.  The backend developer doesn't understand how fonts.com (or front end development) works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The developer didn't realize how these services worked.  So i explained it to him.